# Python list index splitting and manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, list

My question seems simple, but for a novice to python like myself this is starting to get too complex for me to get, so here's the situation:

I need to take a list such as:

```
L = [(a, b, c), (d, e, d), (etc, etc, etc), (etc, etc, etc)]
```

and make each index an individual list so that I may pull elements from each index specifically. The problem is that the list I am actually working with contains hundreds of indices such as the ones above and I cannot make something like:

```
L_new = list(L['insert specific index here'])
```

for each one as that would mean filling up the memory with hundreds of lists corresponding to individual indices of the first list and would be far too time and memory consuming from my point of view. So my question is this, how can I separate those indices and then pull individual parts from them without needing to create hundreds of individual lists (at least to the point where I wont need hundreds of individual lines to create them).

Comment: You don't have to do anything for this. You can just add another index and it will work. L[0][0] will give a, L[0][1] will give b, L[2][1] will give etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misreading your question, but I'm inclined to say that you don't actually have to do anything to be able to index your tuples. See my comment, but: `L[0][0]` will give `"a"`, `L[0][1]` will give `"b"`, `L[2][1]` will give `"etc"` etc...

If you really want a clean way to turn this into a list of lists you could use a list comprehension:

```
cast = [list(entry) for entry in L]
```

In response to your comment: if you want to access across dimensions I would suggest list comprehension. For your comment specifically:

```
crosscut = [entry[0] for entry in L]
```

In response to comment 2: This is largely a part of a really useful operation called slicing. Specifically to do the referenced operation you would do this:

```
multiple_index = [entry[0:3] for entry in L]
```

Depending on your readability preferences there are actually a number of possibilities here:

```
list_of_lists = []
for sublist in L:
    list_of_lists.append(list(sublist))

iterator = iter(L)
for i in range(0,iterator.__length_hint__()):
    return list(iterator.next())
    # Or yield list(iterator.next()) if you want lazy evaluation
```

Comment: This is a good start, as I didn't know this could be done in python, so I thank you for that bit of knowledge, however I am still wondering how I would effectively call (for example) L[:][0], would that work for pulling a* from all of the indices in this list? *(a is just an example, assuming it is the first index in the parentheses)

Comment: Thanks very much, completely solved the issue with that updated response! Well..mostly haha, can I assign several 'entries' to the crosscut, such as [entry[0, 1, 2] for entry in L] ?

Comment: Thanks for that edit, and I'm sorry I didn't make it more clear, but I am trying to access something closer to this: [entry[0, 8, 13] for entry in L] meaning that the slice will not go from 1-3 but actually needs to be separate indices, thanks for any help you can give, and have given.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a list of tuples, access them like a list of lists

```
L[3][2]
```

will get the second element from the 3rd tuple in your list L

Answer (score 2):

Two way of using inner lists:

```
for index, sublist in enumerate(L):
    # do something with sublist
    pass
```

or with an iterator

```
iterator = iter(L)
sublist = L.next() # <-- yields the first sublist
```

in both case, `sublist` elements can be reached via

- direct index

> 

```
sublist[2]
```

- iteration

> 

```
iterator = iter(sublist)
iterator.next()  # <-- yields first elem of sublist

for elem in sublist:
    # do something with my elem
    pass
```